# Scroll down and up using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

**Error: Wait timed out after 3005ms**

I used `window.scrollTo(0,200)` for scrolling the web page down. The code is as follows:

```
browser.wait(function() {
          browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,200);').then(function () {
          })
        }, 3000);
```

**REQUIREMENT:** *NFAR after scroll down. It should scroll up after waiting for 3000ms.*

To scroll up I wrote the code as follows

```
browser.wait(function() {
          browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,-200);').then(function () {
          })
        }, 10000);
```

Is multiple `browser.wait` causing errors? Please suggest some best way to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`browser.wait` does not 'wait' after performing some action. It is a function to keep retrying the function inside until it returns true OR reaches the specified timeout (if it reaches the timeout it will throw an error).

Since you are not returning anything inside your function, it will always return 'undefined' and thus never be true, and will throw the error that it timed out in 3000 ms.

The code you probably want uses `browser.sleep`

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,200);').then(function() {
    browser.sleep(3000);
}).then(function() {
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Finally I found my solution!!**

The following code I found helpful to remove the error.

```
var elm = element.all(by.css('.your-css-class')).get(9);
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());

elm.click();
```

Basically this allows you scroll into your view..

Comment: If this is your solution, then your original question was worded very poorly. Glad you figured it out though!

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/319) on protractor relating to this.
Perhaps this will help you:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,200);').then(function () {
    browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function () {
        // ...
    })
})
```

Comment: My issue  is **Wait timed out after 3005ms**, the open issue you mentioned is all about **element not clickable**,